# jQuery selector for appending + symbol to first instance of span class only

Tags: jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I have an accordion navigation quick launch in SharePoint. the accordion works great, however, i am attempting to append an icon to the top level `ul` headings in SharePoint. unfortunately, all of the `ul` and `li` no matter the level have a span class of `menu-item-text.` I cannot for the life of me figure out which selector to use to append the icon on ONLY the top level headings, and not the subsequent list items located under the sub-menus.

here is the jQuery.

```
var parent = $("#zz12_V4QuickLaunchMenu > ul > li:has('ul')");
parent.find("li span.menu-item-text:first").append("<b>+</b>");
parent.closest("li").find("> ul").hide();
parent.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var childUL = $(this).closest("li").find("> ul");
    var isVisible = childUL.is(":visible");
    if (isVisible) {
        childUL.slideUp();
    } else {
        childUL.slideDown();
    }
});
```

the html, however, can be viewed via the jsfiddle link below. [it's exhaustive].

ETA:  if i take out the `find("li span.menu-item-text:first")` portion, the script works as intended.  however, the + is moved to the bottom of the UL if the UL is expanded.  I am trying to prevent that by somehow putting the + in the same `<span>` that the title is wrapped in.

please see my jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/m30nar2p/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:first-child` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) instead of [`:first` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

> While `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent.

```
parent.find("li span.menu-item-text:first-child").append("<b>+</b>");
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qz5eqLqd/)

Comment: thanks, however this is not what i am looking for and  i have tried that selector.. i am trying to put the '+' on the TOP LEVEL links, not the list items in the submenu.   as you see, when  all of the UL are collpased, there is no + to indicate that the ul has other links..

Comment: @user2004758, Seems you need `parent.find("span.menu-item-text:first").append("<b>+</b>")`